# Add a product to cart without going through the event checkout_cart_product_add_after

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, event-observer, addtocart

Currently we have the problem, that users can buy/put products in the cart that they should not, because we have a function which is listening to the event checkout_cart_product_add_after. This Event is for example triggerd, if you try to add a product to the cart from the product detail page, or via URL (https://www.foobar.de/checkout/cart/add/product/1337/form_key/adsfXXddeee/).

Do you have a idea how the users can do this? Is this a known Magento bug?

PHP 5.6.x
M1.9.2.4

Answer (score 1):

What I can think of:

- added as related product. It might even be possible to get any product added as related product if the id is known, I'm not sure how they are validated
- if the product was buyable before: reorder from customer account or login as customer with saved cart

Comment: > added as related product. It might even be possible to get any 
> productadded as related product if the id is known, I'm not sure how they > are validated 


How would you do this, if related products are not available?

> if the product was buyable before: reorder from customer account or 
> login as customer with saved cart

This was not the case.

The current plan is to use also the event sales_order_save_before and remove the product from the quote in this event, but if feels like a hack...

Comment: You can probably manipulate an add to cart POST request  to contain `related_products[]=42` to add the product with id 42 together with the current one